# Accessing an object property without knowing it's parent with a for in loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to access a value retrieved from an external API. Specifically, it's a shortened URL. The shortener takes the long URL saves it as an object itself within an object and places the shortened URL within this object (see screenshot).

I won't know the exact value of the long URL so I am trying to use a for in loop to access the shortUrl (since I know that is always the name if it's key) and for now print it to the console.

I get variations of undefined, [object, object] or null.

What is missing here?

```js
    longUrl = "longUrl=" + longUrl;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url:'http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=3f5f69733156cce575b9a7ab1783ff4f4f0a8b5c&format=json&',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: longUrl, 
        success:  function(data){
            for (var shortUrl in data){
                if(data.hasOwnProperty(shortUrl)) {
                    console.log(data[shortUrl]);
                }
                
            }
            
        }
});
```

[image]

Comment: You have missed the closing brackets for $.ajax method

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, Sorry about that they were below some commented out lines. I'll edit above.

Comment: Your code doesn't print "undefined" or "null". It prints the properties - "", OK, 0, {results}

Answer (score 1):

Please try use `data.results` instead of `data`:

```
var shortURLs = [];
for(var key in data.results) {
    shortURLs.push(data.results[key].shortUrl);
}
console.log(shortURLs);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var longUrl = {longUrl: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417777/accessing-an-object-property-without-knowing-its-parent-with-a-for-in-loop/38417810#38417810"};
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url:'http://api.shortswitch.com/shorten?apiKey=3f5f69733156cce575b9a7ab1783ff4f4f0a8b5c&format=json&',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: longUrl, 
        success:  function(data){
            var shortURLs = [];
            for(var key in data.results) {
              shortURLs.push(data.results[key].shortUrl);
            }
            console.log(shortURLs);
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could update your answer to explain that the OP needs to be looking in `data.results` rather than in `data`? (Leaving them to figure that out from your code is less helpful.)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. It is clear that OP has said "I get variations of undefined, [object, object] or null". So, it cannot be trying to iterate the wrong property.

Comment: Ow ! he can spot the difference easily ! However, I will !

Comment: @CharlieH - The OP is definitely trying to iterate the wrong property. The values they want are within `data.results`, not `data`.

Comment: But he says he get 'undefined' and 'null' - which is not the case when I run his code. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can your answer say why he get 'undefined' and 'null' when he iterates the root object?

Comment: @CharlieH null it's possible if he can't access the remote server !

Comment: @CharliH - What the OP *says* they're doing and what their code *shows* they're doing are apparently two different things. I would guess that they've tried other variations on that code and that some of those other variations were what resulted in undefined or null or whatever.

Comment: @CharlieH Please we can't know what the OP has tried to get those variations !! please be reasonable !

Comment: @nnnnnn So, this has to be clarified with the OP before providing an answer. This answer might not transpire the information he needs.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - If you have such a doubt about the question, please use comments to discuss it with the OP

Comment: @CharlieH why asking something CLEAR and OBVIOUS! I've tested the code it produces the expected results. that's the point ! What the author has tried is enormous and he shares it just to highlight his efforts not seeking any explanations !  Even the OP question is *What is missing here?* not *Why I get these variations* !

Comment: Reproducing his code doesn't give us 'undefined' - but it does for him in his envirnment. Just changing the object as done in your answer is still going to give him wrong results in his environment. So your answer is simply useless.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH, thanks for the reply. Would you mind explaining why var shortUrls has to be an array?

Comment: @Somethingismissing The API `results` may contain more than one result or just in case. You can easily access the first result `shortURLs[0]`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Interesting. Thanks! As far as I'm aware the api will only ever issue one result so I would think I could just write `var shortUrls;` but that doesn't return the needed value.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on the right track with iterating through the object's property and accessing that key. Based on your example data, you should be checking `data.result` not `data`.

Here's an example plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7De7ZVPHz7x2n1OcKXmi?p=info

Here's the relevant code:

```
var data = {
  errorMessage: "",
  statusCode: "OK",
  errorCode: "0",
  results: {
    "http://hello?cmp=EXP:da:paid::320x50": {
      hash: "B3uXHF",
      shortUrl: "http://at.law.com/B3uXHf",
      longUrl: "http://hello?cmp=EXP:da:paid::320x50"
    }
  }
};

function getShortURL(data) {
  for (var property in data.results) {
    if (data.results.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      return data.results[property].shortUrl;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getShortURL(data));
```

Since you do not know the longUrl, you just need to access that object's child properties to access the shortUrl key. You really are just iterating through the indexes of the object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. It is clear that OP has said "I get variations of undefined, [object, object] or null". So, it cannot be trying to iterate the wrong property.

Comment: Based on the OP's example response body, there is no distinguishable way to identify why they would be receiving undefined. So it's unfair to -1. The [object Object] is due to the result property being an object. Null is also not identifiable based on the response body. My answer helps the OP in the areas that their description allows for.

Comment: No - if there is a difficulty to understand a part of the problem, you should use comments to discuss it with the OP. Can you answer say why he gets 'undefined' when accessed the root object?

Comment: My answer answers his question "Accessing an object property without knowing it's parent with a for in loop". Do you want to get into the specifics or ideologies of answering a question on StackOverflow? Undefined is most likely received if the server responds back with an invalid object. But the for loop would throw an error when attempting to iterate the undefined object. Again, this is only an assumption based on the information provided. External server API contracts are not referenced.

Comment: //Undefined is most likely received if the server responds back with an invalid object - So, that maybe the real issue. Help him overcome that - not something you assume about it.

Comment: That's outside of the OP's control if the server is responding back with a 200 (inside the success callback of the $ajax GET) and is still returning back an undefined object. The API contract should be throwing a 400 status code (bad request) if the OP is not interacting with the API correctly. The interaction must be mildly accurate if they were able to get a complete response body at some point in testing.

Comment: You should post this comment to OP. That helps him - not your answer.

Comment: @CharlieH - We know the server is responding with a valid object in JSON-P format, otherwise jQuery wouldn't call the `success` handler. We know that object's format because the OP posted a picture of it. Both this and the other answer show the correct code needed to access that data, fixing the obvious error in the OP's code. It's *possible* there is some other problem too, but far more likely that the OP is confused after trying different variations on their own code. So saying these answers don't help is just plain wrong - if you don't agree with them, downvote and move on.

Comment: @nnnnnn **// It's possible there is some other problem too**

Don't keep a doubt. Discuss it with the OP through comments. Then provide the correct answer leaving the guessing game. That's what I'm trying to point out. 

And also it is my right to reason out the down vote through comments. On the other hand you have no right to tell me that I should move on after down voting.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the confusion.

@SeanPerkins, I've added the getshortUrl function under the success key in $.ajax. 

I'm just getting the entire json object (from data on) printed to the console. is there somewhere else I should put it.

Comment: @Somethingismissing I would place the function outside of the ajax call, but access the function from inside the success callback.